# How can I filter my data based on multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Okay, so I have an array of objects which is the data I want to filter:

```
const posts = [
{
 hairday: '2',
 products: ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4'],
 rating: '2',
 drying: 'diffuser'
},
{
 hairday: '2',
 products: ['product6', 'product7', 'product8', 'product9'],
 rating: '4',
 drying: 'air dry'
},
{
 hairday: '3',
 products: ['product10', 'product11', 'product13', 'product14'],
 rating: '3',
 drying: 'air dry'
},
{
 hairday: '4',
 products: ['product15', 'product26', 'product37', 'product14'],
 rating: '5',
 drying: 'towel dry'
},
]
```

I would like to filter the above data by multiple conditions. Here is an example object of conditions:

```
{
 products: ['product1', 'product13'],
 hairday: ['2', '3'],
 drying: ['air dry', 'diffuser'],
 rating: []
}
```

So I want to get all of the `post` objects that match at least one of the items in each array.

So, the filtered items should have product1 OR product13 AND hairday 2 OR hairday 3 AND drying airdry OR drying diffuser AND any rating.

What's the best way to go through this? Is my filter object structured in the best way?
Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more robust solution that doesn't require listing the keys manually, you can use `Object.keys()` to iterate through your criteria object, and then compare individual objects in the `post` array against it:

```
const filtered = posts.filter(post => {
  const conditionKeys = Object.keys(conditions);
  const fulfillments = conditionKeys.map(k => {
    const condition = conditions[k];
    
    // If we encounter an empty array, then criteria is always met
    if (condition.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    
    // Enforces that as long as ONE subcondition is met (`OR`)
    return condition.filter(v => post[k].includes(v)).length > 0;
  });
  
  // Enforce that EVERY condition must be met (`AND`)
  // A condition is considered met as long as it is true
  return fulfillments.every(x => x);
});
```

When iterating through individual condition (hairday, products, etc.), we simply want to check if your object includes one or more of the listed values (i.e. of the two arrays intersect in anyway). If there is an intersection, the length will be >0, otherwise it will be 0.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const posts = [{
    hairday: '2',
    products: ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4'],
    rating: '2',
    drying: 'diffuser'
  },
  {
    hairday: '2',
    products: ['product6', 'product7', 'product8', 'product9'],
    rating: '4',
    drying: 'air dry'
  },
  {
    hairday: '3',
    products: ['product10', 'product11', 'product13', 'product14'],
    rating: '3',
    drying: 'air dry'
  },
  {
    hairday: '4',
    products: ['product15', 'product26', 'product37', 'product14'],
    rating: '5',
    drying: 'towel dry'
  },
];

const conditions = {
  products: ['product1', 'product13'],
  hairday: ['2', '3'],
  drying: ['air dry', 'diffuser'],
  rating: []
};

const filtered = posts.filter(post => {
  const fulfillments = Object.keys(conditions).map(k => {
    const condition = conditions[k];
    
    // If we encounter an empty array, then criteria is always met
    if (condition.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    
    return condition.filter(v => post[k].includes(v)).length > 0;
  });
  
  return fulfillments.every(x => x);
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: That `map / filter(x => x) / equal length` bit could probably be replaced with an `every`.

Comment: I meant a bit more than that.  This could just be `posts.filter(post => Object.keys (conditions).every(k => { /* same code here */ }))`.  As well as being cleaner, it also short-circuits as soon as it can.

Comment: Also replacing the `.filter(...) .length > 0` with a `some (...)`, we can get to `const filtered = posts .filter (post => Object .keys (conditions) .every (k => conditions [k] .length === 0 || conditions [k] .some (v => post [k] .includes(v))))`, which is much simpler than either your original version or my somewhat similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I might write a fairly generic version this way:

```js
const findMatches = (filters, xs) => 
  xs .filter (x => Object .entries (filters) .every (([name, vals]) =>
    vals.length == 0 ||
    (Array .isArray (x [name])
      ? x [name] .some (val => vals .includes (val))
      : vals .includes (x [name]))
  ))

const posts = [{hairday: '2', products: ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4'], rating: '2', drying: 'diffuser'}, {hairday: '2', products: ['product6', 'product7', 'product8', 'product9'], rating: '4', drying: 'air dry'}, {hairday: '3', products: ['product10', 'product11', 'product13', 'product14'], rating: '3', drying: 'air dry'}, {hairday: '4', products: ['product15', 'product26', 'product37', 'product14'], rating: '5', drying: 'towel dry'}]
const filters = {products: ['product1', 'product13'], hairday: ['2', '3'], drying: ['air dry', 'diffuser'], rating: []}

console .log (findMatches (filters, posts))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The code knows nothing about posts, products, hairdays, etc.  It simply filters a list of objects against a conditions object.

There's something I don't like about this, though.  The special handling for the empty array (`ratings`) makes it feel like that's a mistaken design.  I would suggest that if you don't have any matching values, you simply don't include it in your conditions object.  So we would remove `ratings1 to get just

```js
const conditions = {
  products: ['product1', 'product13'],
  hairday: ['2', '3'],
  drying: ['air dry', 'diffuser'],
};
```

This makes more logical sense to me, as the other conditions all say, essentially, that the value in your object must be one of the given list (or in the case of an array one of your elements must be one of the given list).  The empty `ratings` object breaks that.

That would simplify the code slightly to

```js
const findMatches = (filters, xs) => 
  xs .filter (x => Object .entries (filters) .every (([name, vals]) =>
    Array .isArray (x [name])
      ? x [name] .some (val => vals .includes (val))
      : vals .includes (x [name])
  ))
```

There are several inefficiencies in these versions.  We fetch `x [name]` twice for each `x`, which is probably not a big deal, but we also call `Object .entries` on the `filters` for every value.  If this function turned out to be a bottleneck in your application, you might want to fix them.  This version would clean them both up, and also allow you to make a reusable function for a given set of conditions:

```js
const findMatches = (filters) => {
  const toMatch = Object .entries (filters)
  return (xs) => 
    xs .filter (x => toMatch .every (([name, vals]) => {
      const val = x [name]
      return Array .isArray (val)
        ? val .some (val => vals .includes (val))
        : vals .includes (val)
    }))
}
```

And you would call it slightly differently:

```
const myFilter = findMatches (filters)
// ... later
console .log (myFilter (posts))
```

But I would not bother unless this turns out to be an application bottleneck, which seems unlikely.  The first, or ideally second, version is much cleaner.